# An SNL skit or a SNL skit?

Tags: indefinite-article, initialisms

An SNL skit or a SNL skit?

I am pretty sure it's "an", but I wasn't exactly sure, because I was news articles use "a" instead.

Comment: I wrote an answer on a/an once! Glad to see it's come up again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pronounce the letters individually as "Ess En Ell" (which would be common), the first sound is a vowel, and we would say "**an** SNL skit." If we speak the words "Saturday Night Live," the first sound is a consonant, and we would say "**a** Saturday Night Live skit."

In print, since you wrote SNL as an acronym, the reader is most likely to "hear" the letters individually as "Ess En Ell." We should therefore write "**an** SNL skit."